# Is it necessary to have Submit button for each <form>?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, web-standards, screen-readers

If I'm using a dropdown using `<select>` is it ok. I'm asking in terms of Web Accessibility, Web Standards.

```
<form action="#" class="country-selection">
    <select>
        <option title="images/india.jpg">India</option>
        <option title="images/india.jpg">USA</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you're actually asking here?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's VERY confusing to screen reader users when, while simply reading the options of a select, it'll force them into a completely new page (if we open a select, we'll only read the options and close it. When a screen reader do that, it'll trigger the action, except if it uses the not known at all keyboard shortcut Alt+Shift+Down arrow). +1 to answer from @Jukka K. Korpela and comment from stringy

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because the page should work without client-side scripting too. The proper way is to include a real `action` attribute value, referring to a server-side script, and include a submit button, because that is the only way to ensure submittability when scripting is off. You can wrap it inside a `noscript` element so that it does not appear when it is not needed, i.e. when client-side scripting is enabled:

```
<noscript><input type=button value=Change></noscript>
```

The `title` attribute values may be displayed or otherwise presented to the user, so they should either contain something sensible (not URLs) or be absent. If you need to include some data for client-side processing, use `data-` attributes.

Comment: This feels like a rather outdated answer. It also doesn't answer the Web Accessibility part.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is specifically called out as a failure in WCAG 2.0: [F37: Failure of Success Criterion 3.2.2 due to launching a new window without prior warning when the status of a radio button, check box or select list is changed](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/failures.html#F37).

Comment: The form will validate without a submit button. But it will fail WCAG2 requirements. Don't surprise your users with unusual uses of common form elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any `submit` button it is acceptable after all it is an element of `form` tag and if it is not required you may not add it with in `form`. This will not broke any web standard.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's ok, noone is forcing a submit button on you, but you probably won't need an action on the form either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the form when the user makes a selection, try this

```
<form action="#" class="country-selection">

      <select onChange="javascript:submit()">

        <option title="images/india.jpg">India</option>

        <option title="images/india.jpg">USA</option>

      </select>

    </form>
```